# How to change my jupyter notebook working directory?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I would like to change my jupyter notebook working directory, how should I proceed?

If it is possible, I also want to keep the current working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it using `--notebook-dir=`

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=$HOME/Documents/MyProject
```

and like always use it without `--notebook-dir=` to get it run in current working directory:

```
jupyter notebook
```

---

If you always work on same directory then create an alias:

```
alias my_jupyter='jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=$HOME/Documents/MyProject'
```

Now when you run `my_jupyter` "Jupyter" will be run at `$HOME/Documents/MyProject`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a stupid question: so I just run the line `alias ...` line directly, and I do not need to place this `alias ...` line into `~/.bashrc`, is it right?

Comment: @ShengBi If you want it permanently which you want I guess, then you have to out it in `.bashrc`.